# Multicol : fit the text on a column

Tags: multicol, multicolumn

Is there a way to fit the following text `\lipsum[2-5]` to one column (the first one) ?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,landscape,DIV=30]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{multicols*}{3}
\lipsum[2-5]
%
\vfill
\vspace*{\fill}
\columnbreak
\lipsum[2-3]

%
\vfill
\vspace*{\fill}
\columnbreak
~

\vfill\null
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Smaller size? I'm not sure what kind of answer you are expecting. We're not talking about one word here; there is simply too much text for one column.

Comment: My goal would be to find a way to locally reduce the font size so that the first `lipsum` fits in the first column. I have tested things with adjustbox, but I get an error every time.

Comment: To use adjustbox, you first need a box.  \parbox will do.

Comment: I tried replacing the first `lipsum` by `\begin{adjustbox}{max height=0.5\paperheight,max width=\columnwidth}
\parbox{\columnwidth}{\lipsum[2-5]}
\end{adjustbox}` : it's do the trick, but what is the height of a column in multicols ? I would like to change `0.5\paperheight` into the real length.

Answer (score 1):

Try along these lines:

```
% colprob.tex  SE 584776

\documentclass[11pt,landscape,DIV=30]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{multicols*}{3}
{\tiny
\lipsum[2-5]

}
End 2--5.
%
\vfill
\vspace*{\fill}
\columnbreak
\lipsum[2-3]

%
\vfill
\vspace*{\fill}
\columnbreak
~

\vfill\null
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a way that would do this automatically (calculate the best possible font size to avoid the large empty space at the bottom).

Comment: @jowe_19 You never mentioned "automatically" in your question.